# Page numbering and the correct place of appendix sections

Tags: page-numbering, appendices, report

I want to add an appendix with continuous page numbering to my thesis, which is a `report` document class. I have tried doing as follows, but all of the sections are shown in the first page of the appendix and then the tables and figures appear. I want each title to be for a certain group of table/figures, however.

```
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix} 
\section{Univariate Models Additional Results\label{Univariate}}
\section{Multivariate Models Additional Results\label{Multivariatevariate}}
\section{Logistic Regression Additional Results\label{Logit}}
\section{Models Performance Additional Results\label{all}}
```

It looks like this in the table of contents:
[image]

and like this in the report itself:
[image]

So mainly two questions:

1. How to have continuous page numbering for the appendix?
2. How to put each section of the appendix (A.1,A.2,...) on the corresponding page with relevant table and figures?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{…}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not shown what you have done. You have to enter the tables and figures for each section after the `\section` command. Perhaps they are too large for the page in which case put `\clearpage` before the next `\section`.

Normally the bibliography will not make changes to the page numbering nor will the `\appendix` macro so I have no idea why your appendix page numbering is reset to start at 1 following your bibliography.

Comment: It puts the sections in the right place but the tables start at the end of the page where section name is. I am also using ```\usepackage{flafter}``` so the tables/figures will be after the reference points.

Comment: Nevermind, got it fixed.