# Bibliography numbering does not show in Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, numbering

In the Beamer environment I have a bibliography at the end as:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{frame}
```

The bibliography comes out as [image]

As you can see the numbering does not show. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228. That's the same link that you were pointed to in your last question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574182) :).

Comment: [How do I get numbered entries in a beamer bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124256/134144) might be worth having a look at. Apart from that, please prepare a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.